# Родственны ли слова “казнь” и “наказание”?

Tags: этимология

Родственны ли слова “казнь” и “наказание”? Они похожи по написанию, а также известно, что "наказание" - одно из значений слова "казнь".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, эти слова родственны. Рассмотрим этимологии каждого и выделим общее:

1. **Казнь** — лишение жизни как высшая карающая мера. Из праслав. *казнь, производного с суф. -нь от глагола ***казати** (*казити?), точнее, от корня *каз- до тематического расширения ее суф. -а-ти.
2. **Наказание** — мера воздействия на того, кто совершил проступок, преступление; перен. о ком-, чём-л. трудном, тяжёлом, неприятном (разг.). Из праслав. *наказаньйе, производного имени действия с суф. -ньйе от глаг. *наказати.
3. ***Наказати** от ***казати**.

***Вывод:*** как видно, оба слова восходят к одному и тому же праслав. глаголу *казати, а значит, родственны.

Источник: этимологический словарь А. К. Шапошникова

Answer (score -1):

**Этимология Князь За-кон Наказ Знак Казнь**   http://www.proza.ru/2015/10/12/694                                              Все аффиксы … (приставки, суффиксы, окончания) – это наследники, когда то существовавщих, отдельных слов !
А. Зализняк 
https://youtu.be/6XxAUWFt1wY    https://youtu.be/6XxAUWFt1wY?t=3684   1:01:25

Фрагмент статьи "Смыслы в звуках ..." - http://www.proza.ru/2015/07/20/338

Закон (З*-Кон) = готовый законченный (совершенный) Кон. Т. е. если Кон (космологический "абстрактный" живой принцип) стал для человека (людей) готовым (сформулированным - законченным, осознанным) - тогда он За-Кон.
Закон = З-К-Н = Законченный Кон Явленый. Закон конечно ЯВЛЕН - по определению. 
ЗаКоН = З-К-Н = К-З-Н = Казнь (нижнелужецкий) - ЗАКОН ! 
Да - в реальном (нижнелужицком - венедском) языке:
"Казнь" - означает современное русское "Закон". И это первое основное значение ! 
Википедия:
«Нижнелужицкий язы;к (также вендский; самоназвания: dolnoserbska r;c, 
dolnoserb;;ina) — один из двух литературных языков лужичан, иначе 
лужицких сербов, распространённый в исторической области Нижняя Лужица в 
земле Бранденбург в Восточной Германии. Относится к лужицкой подгруппе 
западнославянских языков.»
Древнеславянский :
Кнежис се - Правило, управление
Кнез - князь
Знанк - свидетель
Заказаш - запретить
Мукарь – властелин повелитель; (мучитель ?)

Закон = З-К-Н = Н-К-З = Наказ (польский) - ЗАКОН приказ (веление).

Князь = К-Н-З = Кон Явленый Законченный (готовый, совершенно) = З-К-Н "=" ЗаКоН. 
Князь - НЕСОМНЕННО  от согласных корней  К*Н* и З*  (Кон Кан Кун, Нак, ...), как и - Закон Наказ Знак  Казна  Казнь  и т.п.
Князь = К-Н-З = Кон Явленый Законченный (готовый, совершенный) = 
= З-К-Н (Н*К*З, К*З*Н, К*З*Н)  "=" ЗаКоН  Знак  Наказ  Казнь  Казна. 
Т. е. Князь это – Власть в разных формах :
Законник – законодатель-законопроводник, 
правитель-наказник (наказодаватель), 
наказатель-казнитель, 
знакодержатель (даватель), 
казнодержатель (распорядитель).
Знак-символ княжеской власти (печать, мандат, …), имел силу Закона и предъявитель (пользователь) такого Знака мог проводить (реализовывать) Наказы, так же имевших силу Закона – были обязательны к выполнению под страхом Казни.
Сравните :
Закон-Князь
Загар - Грязь 
Замор(ить) – Мразъ ( др.славян. – сильный холод, стужа ) 
Заклад -  Кладезь 
Знак - Наказ.
Закут - Кутуз(ка)
Заря -  Раз*, рез (рана)
Зал - Лаз Луза
Затор – Тор* Торос Стора Штора Шора
Запор – Пор* Парус Порог Порез Пирс Парша Пароша  Порось
За-бор – Борз* берёза
Зрада - Рада*

Соответстно 3и КОРНЯ в КНяЗь. 
Всеобщий корни - К и Н, не мог не использоваться для названия Правителя, но "За" (как префикс) был уже занят. "Закон" (Сила-власть-порядок-правило) - поглобальней чем собственно его проводник-символ (Князь-правитель) в понятийном смысле-контексте. Но поскольку "З" неЗаменим (в КОНтексте)  - осталось "Княз*".
В словенском Knez Kneza. Но произносить Зь легче чем Зъ, ну а трудности лишние ни к чему - говорим "князЬ".

Князь = К-Н-З = К-З-Н = Kiezen >>>
Kiezen (нидерланд.) - выбирать, принимать решение, знак, говорить, являть показывать, указывать назначать, двигать.
Kanжi (Camsa) - раз единица один одни одно.
Источник (основа) слова - КОРНИ - суть конкретные согласные звуки (фонемы), характер их огласовки (слоговой) не существенен с точки зрения смысло-содержания (смысло-образования) в слове.
Слово КЪНЯЗЬ образовано из трёх явных фонем корней - *К* *Н* *З*, как и слова **ЗАКОН НАКАЗ ЗНАК КАЗНЬ КАЗНА** ...
В древнеславянском Кан = Хан.
В венгерском и ныне, слово "Кан" имеет единственное значение - Хан (Князь-правитель).
В японском:
Слово "Кана" означает "японская письменность - правила письма" (Japanese syllabary); и правила (как порядок) это всегда ОГРАНИЧЕНИЯ (пределы).
KuNi-shu - Князь (правитель). Состоит из двух знаков - "Государство и Главный ".
tai-KuN -  : Князь (монарх правитель). Состоит из двух знаков - "Великий и Правитель".

Санскрит: 
Han -  убийца,  причина того что будет выполнено, КАЗНИТЕЛЬ (в словаре - казнить)
Hana  - прекращение, отказ, отсутствие, избавление, убийство, потеря, побег, ушедший удалившийся.

......................................

Поскольку фонемы  K и N - это реальные всеобщие корни, то естественно что каждый из них и 
их сочетание ( K*N) в самых разных языках - связаны со смыслом "КОН-КНЯЗЬ" :

Ko (тамильский) - Князь
Kyky (финский) - Князь
Kaiki (Latgalian) - Конец
jээk (эстонский) - Князь
Key (курдский) - Князь
Ku (Northern Qiang) - Власть
Kabaka (ганда) - Князь
Kukomya (ганда) - Конец
      Японский :
Ka – Ограничение предел конец
Kyoku – предел …

Kokuou - Князь
ikou - Власть
Kai - Граница :
Kokkyou
Kyoukai 
waku
wakaku
Kyouiki
Ka - Конец :
ake
Kingu - Князь : 
Kunishu
Kunou
Kokuou 
Kunishu
taikun
ninkun

Kenryoku - Власть :
rikikan
Kensei
Kanri - Контроль :
Kanryou 
Kantoku
Kansei 
Kankatsu
genkai - Предел :
Kyokugen
Kante - Граница :
henkyou
Keisen
rinkaku
Kan - Конец :
nochi
danraku
Kkeut (корейский) - Конец

```
  Турецкий:
```

uc - Предел
Kiyi - Граница
аяк (киргизский) - Конец
чик (татарский) - Конец граница предел
      Туркменский:
cak, cэk - Предел
cэk  jэhek - Граница 
ayak - Предел :
uc
shoh (узбекский) - Князь
Kuch (узбекский) - Власть
cak (тоск. албанский) - Предел
ike (игбо) - Власть
ikoi (Kah) - Власть
Qiu (китайский) - Граница
khh(иврит) - Власть
Санскрит:
NI - руководящий ведущий, НАЧАЛЬНИК
NAya - лидер
NayaNa -  Контроль, управление руководство, глаз
uNNata -  выдающийся великий
Nayate {Ni} - быть в НАЧАЛЕ или главным, управлять руководить вести.

Kinz (дзонг-кэ) -  Князь
Kine, Kini (bavarian) - Князь
Kin (Takia) -  Князь
Konu (кариб) - Князь
Kione (мэнский) - Князь
Konu (Saramaccan) - Князь
Keni;s (латышский) - Князь
Konc (нижнелужицкий) - Князь
       Словацкий:
vykon - Власть :
Koncovy 
hrana - Граница :
zanik 
wynik (польский) - Конец
jaчina (хорватский) - Власть
      Чешский:
vykon - Власть :
mocnina
mocnost
prikon
zahon, hrana - Граница
sklonek - Конец
Kaanki (Iraqw) - Конец
K;an (арчи) - Конец
Khhan (bench) - Князь
Kana, ancala (бенгальский) - граница
      Хинди:
ltechnique -  Контроль
Kinara -  Граница
          Тайский:
Khun - Князь
x;a nac - Власть
       Тамильский :
Kon -  Князь :
aracan, iracan, araican
komakan
ican
nayakan
ma-racan
Kon -  Власть :
cantam 
KaNtam -  Конец предел, разум, стебель, кувшин
matanku - Контроль
Kanku -  Предел, граница 
Kincal - Предел :
taka;
nikkirakam
pankaram 
cantippu - Граница
konai - Конец :
avacanam
nikkam
Kantam -  Kонец, предел
an;cukattu (каннада) - Предел
mugin;cu (телугу) - Конец
       Персидский:
shahanh - Князь
tngna - Предел
Knarh - Граница
Ntha - Конец

Kinnek (люксембургский) - Князь
Koongs, koon;;; (скольт-саамский) - Князь
          Норвежский букмол:
Kong, konge - Князь
forsterkning - Власть
rakne - Конец :
hen
         Шведский:
Kung, konung - Князь
inskr;nka - Предел
kantrabatt - Граница
anhalla - Конец
          Финский:
Kunkku, kuningas - Князь
ohjain - Контроль : 
Komento
valtakunta 
Kaventaa - Предел
Kukkapenkki - Граница
Nokka - Конец
        Староанглийский:
cyning - Власть
hring - Граница
Kuning (Old Saxon) - Князь
Keunig, Konig (германский) - Князь
Kingi (маори) - Князь
Koning (африкаанс) - Князь
Kingu (Coastal Swahili) - Князь
ukingo (суахили) - Граница
Kugenga (киньяруанда) - Контроль
Kaananke (Western Niger Fulfulde) - Князь
       Кёльш:
Kunnisch - Князь
angk - Конец
Confein (Istriot) - граница
Cunfin (Ladin) - граница
;kun th; (Southern Qiang) - граница
        Латинский:
censura - Контроль :
conprimo 
constringo 
continere
includo 
coangusto - Предел :
concludo 
confinium
contineo 
confine - Граница
concludo - Конец :
conclusio 
consummo 
cornu 
includo
        Румынский:
conduce, comanda - Контроль 
anceta, inceta, incheia - Конец
        Португальский:
comando - Власть :
examinar
examinar - Контроль :
atencao em
nacao - Контроль, власть
conferir - Контроль, власть
confins - Граница :
encerrar 
concluir 
            Нидерландский :
Koning - Князь
Nakijken - Контроль
beknotten - Предел
Kant - Граница
honk, aanhouden - Конец
kening (западно-фризский) - Князь
Kong, konge (датский) - Князь 
          Исландский:
Kongur, konungur - Князь
takmorkun - Предел 
          Фарерский:
Kongur - Князь
Kanna - Контроль
handtaka - Конец
        Греческий:
Kino - Власть
Kyverno, elencho - Контроль
anachoma - Граница
anax (древнегреч.) - Князь
          Гэльский:
ceannsaich - Контроль
ceann - Конец
echui; (бретонский) - Конец
        Валлийский:
cyffin, cyfyngu - Предел
gorffen - Конец :
tranc
         Испанский:
coronar, monarca - Князь
canto - Контроль :
confin
contorno 
contener 
canto - Конец :
blanco 
         Итальянский:
monarca  - Князь
contenimento - Контроль
confine - Конец предел граница
cingere - Граница
conclusione - Конец :
concludere
        Франццузский :
King,  monarque - Князь 
courant,  cardinal - Власть
conduire - Контроль :
coordination
encadrement
circonscrire - Предел
contour - Граница :
flanc
conclusion - Конец :
conclure  confins
         Лушай:
theihna - Власть
chin - Предел
tlang - Граница
          Грузинский:
ghone - Власть
K;ant;i - Граница 
morchena - Конец
        Турецкий:
satranc - Князь
yetenek - Власть
dikine - Конец :
encam
Kal;nt;
netice
nokta
sonu; 
cen (туркменский) - Предел 
      Northern Kurdish:
Kenar - Гранца
Kirin - Конец :
armanc
Kamne
        Урду:
Kn*rwl - Контроль
Kanara - Предел
Khtm krna- Конец
Kendali (индонезийский) - Князь
nhayt (Egyptian Arabic) - Конец
wechuntu (арауканский) - Конец
inkosi (ксоза, зулу) - Князь
Nuku (гавайский) - Конец
Nkomerero (ганда) - Конец
Nkhongono (тумбука) - Власть
hosank;, astiчan, isxanut;yun (армянский) - Князь.

```
    Китайский:
```

Quan li - Власть : 
li zheng 
gong l; 
wang - Князь
Kong zhi - Контроль
Xian - Предел
zhong - Конец, граница
       Корейский:
gwonhan - Власть
Keonteulol - Контроль-управление :
tongjehada 
jehan - Предел :
geughan 
hangye 
hanhada

```
     Вьетнамский:
```

cong suat - Князь :
cung cap luc
cuong quoc
kha nang
nang
quyen
dieu khien - Контроль-управление : 
che ngu 
chinh phu
hon
Khong che
cung -   Предел :
gioui hain
han
nguoi qua quac
ngu
ranh gioi
Khung -  Граница :
giong nhu
gan nh;
duonn
g bien
duong vien
cung -  Конец :
lam xong
chung cuoc
cuu canh 
mau con lai
ngung

Консул, консилиум, конвенция, конклав, ...

СОВЕТ :

Kaunsila - хинди
Koncil  - словацкий
Ca;kam - тамил.
Knkash  - перс. 
Kенес  - киргиз., казах. 
Konsey  - турецкий 
Кинэш  - татар. 
Канаш  - чувашский, марийский 
Кенасы - караим. 
tan;cs - венгер.
sanjikai - япон.
Kh;a mntr;, kh;a krrmk;r - тайский.
"Knesset (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Knesset) - ... from stem of Hebrew kanas "he gathered, assembled, collected."

Вики : 
"Кнессет.  Происходит от ивр. ;;;; «собрание», из корня (k-n-s).
... 
Кена;сса (также кенаса;, кене;са[1]; кене;са;; др.-евр. ;;;;;;;;; караимск. кэнэса) — молитвенный дом караимов в Восточной Европе.
..
Термин «кенасса» происходит от древнееврейского глагола «канос», что подтверждается в книге «Ган-эден» известного караимского богослова XIV в. рабби Агарона Второго Никомодио (1300—1369)[2]. Этим же словом (кенеса;) персидские евреи называют синагогу."